# Add a Google Sheet list of values to the materialize autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, autocomplete, materialize

I'm trying to create a simple web app that add countries to a google sheet. And use materialize autocompletes to assist the user (which simply autocomplete the country, with no images attached). I saw a couple of examples of the materialize autocomplete, but always with a predefined autocomplete list. This is the html I used:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">work_outline</i>
                    <input id="autocomplete-input" type="text" class="autocomplete">
                    <label for="autocomplete-input">Country</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light amber accent-4" id="add_btn">Add country
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(tags).getCountry();
        function tags(data) {
          var availableTags = data;
          $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
              data: availableTags
            });
        };
        document.getElementById("add_btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
        function doStuff() {
            var ucountry = document.getElementById("autocomplete-input").value;
            google.script.run.userClicked(ucountry);
            document.getElementById("autocomplete-input").value = "";
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my code in google script, the function getCountry works, and returns a list of countries. But I didn't succeed in adding them to the materialize autocomplete function.

```
function doGet() {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
    var html = template.evaluate();
    return html;
}
function userClicked(country){
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_GtmVrdD1Es6zQZna_Mv-Rc3JkIu66-q_knQ8aqcUIc/edit#gid=0";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
    ws.appendRow([country]);
}
function getCountry(){
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var list = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues(); // contains countries
  list = list.map(function(r){return r[0]; });
  Logger.log(list);
  var data = "{";
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    data = data + "'" + list[i] + "': null,";    
  }
  data = data.slice(0, -1) + "}";
  Logger.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

This is the information on https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html

```
  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please give access to your sheet

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm a bit ill. But here you have the link, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16a2YTTvcbQeaniFzlaS1j7XbAjtmkJ1teKzmZ3eS-DA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should first run the do get function and afterwords deploy as a web app, then it should work. If it's not working, it's due to the owner rights, then you should just make a copy of the sheet, and then run the do get and the deploy as web app. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: This is a link to the web app, https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxgNryXVK7GcgO1LMtIZ7cxQJ-kIhZiDgX6Q2Elqfsa/dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use web polling to update your page with a set interval such that it always retrieves updated data from the Sheet.*

#### Code:

Piggybacking off the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858958/11551468), **edit your script to include:**

```js
function polling(){
  setInterval(update, 500);
}
function update(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(tags).getCountry();        
}
```

and make sure that you run the `polling()` function on load:

```html
<body onload="polling()">
  <!-- your body goes here -->
</body>
```

Full **page.html:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="polling()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">work_outline</i>
                    <input id="autocomplete-input" type="text" class="autocomplete" placeholder="Country">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light amber accent-4" id="add_btn">Add country
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        function polling(){
          setInterval(update, 500);
        }
        function update(){
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(tags).getCountry();        
        }
        
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(tags).getCountry();
        function tags(list) {
          console.log(list);
          var availableTags = list;
          $("#autocomplete-input").autocomplete({
              source: availableTags
            });
        };
        document.getElementById("add_btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

        function doStuff() {
          var ucountry = document.getElementById("autocomplete-input").value;
          google.script.run.userClicked(ucountry);
          document.getElementById("autocomplete-input").value = "";
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And leave your `code.gs` file unchanged.

#### References:

- [**Stack Overflow** - Creating an autocomplete function in Google Script that works with a list of values from the Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858958/11551468)
- [**Stack Overflow** - Is it possible to import XML or JSON data from a table within a Word online document into Apps Script website as an HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59615146/11551468)

Comment: Thanks @Rafa, you solved some issues. I changed the getCountry() function to get the countries in the right data format. And the succeshandler seems to work, but still only when i manually fill in the countries. When I pass the countries to the availabletags variables, they don't seem to work. So feel free to take another look at it, I will share the link to the document as well, and lots of thanks for the work you did!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_GtmVrdD1Es6zQZna_Mv-Rc3JkIu66-q_knQ8aqcUIc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `getCountry()` function, so it reads the data as an object and not as a string fixed it.

```
function doGet() {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
    var html = template.evaluate();
    return html;
}
function userClicked(country){
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_GtmVrdD1Es6zQZna_Mv-Rc3JkIu66-q_knQ8aqcUIc/edit#gid=0";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
    ws.appendRow([country]);
}
function getCountry(){
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var list = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues(); // contains countries
  list = list.map(function(r){return r[0]; });
  Logger.log(list);
  var data = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    data[list[i]] = null;}
  return data;
}
```

And the html stayed the same:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">work_outline</i>
                    <input id="autocomplete-input" type="text" class="autocomplete">
                    <label for="autocomplete-input">Country</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light amber accent-4" id="add_btn">Add country
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(tags).getCountry();
        function tags(data) {
          var availableTags = data;
          $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
              data: availableTags
            });
        };
        document.getElementById("add_btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
        function doStuff() {
            var ucountry = document.getElementById("autocomplete-input").value;
            google.script.run.userClicked(ucountry);
            document.getElementById("autocomplete-input").value = "";
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```